# Lot of problems while trying to install flask

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv

I am installing flask step by step as in this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QjtW-wnXlUY

At the start I had an error

```
Can't find a default Python
```

yet I managed to fix it.

Now after typing in Git Bash (`py -m venv env`) I get an error saying.

```
"Unable to create process using 'D:\python\python.exe -m venv env'"
```

What can I do about it?

If you wan't me to give you some more information please tell me how to get them since I am a newbie and it will be my pleasure to provide them. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you watch an installation video instead of reading __first__ the [flask installation manual](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/installation/) completely and carefully from top to bottom and __then__ start the installation by entering one command line after the other?

Comment: documentation always feels more difficult for me since I am not a fluent english speaker, I will give it a try now as I am waiting for more answers, thanks!

Comment: I did it and it's the same error.

Comment: yes, yet I downloaded and installed python 3.7.0, and I had to to work my way around microsoft store's python, ( every time I tried to open up python file cmd told me it's not accesable so I turned it off in the microsoft store's settings and then it worked fine later on) So i dont think this has to do with it yet I think it's worth mentioning

Comment: I didn't get to part with activating enviroment since I can't get thru the first part of installation.

Comment: I mean that I created folder needed to install flask but to activate it I need to make it first right?

Comment: Won't the newest version of python 3.8 prevent some of the older libraries or plugins to work? Anyway I will do as you say and repeat all the steps I took in the right order this time.

Comment: Well I guess it solved my problem, I was ready to reinstall windows yet all I needed to do was uninstall one version of python and install another to its deafult directory. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try
`python3 -m venv env`

Also try direct:
`pip install flask`
`python -m flask --version`

I had this problem and this solved it.

Comment: I get the same problem, and python3 -m venv env is not working
bash: python3: command not found

Comment: use python then

Comment: that's what I was using in the first place  :/